# What did I do Wrong Here?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I believe I have made a mistake in the following work I did:
[image]
I have no idea if i have made a mistake or, if somehow, i did everything right. So explain what my mistake is.

Comment: Have you searched about this thre are plenty of questions like this

Comment: Well actually we can talk about "a mistake" it is a more general issue. The main thing about summation of divergent series is that you can't play all the trick that you play with ordinary convergent series so your approach is too naive (not intended to sound rude, I made similar mistakes as your while approaching such theory). If you want to learn more about the subject read Hardy's book or Terence Tao's blog.

Comment: Well, as a joke there is nothing wrong with this (although I don't follow your reasoning on lines 4 and 5). But divergent sequences can not have its individual terms manipulated to "infinite borrowing" which is why *all* these divergent sequence proves are jokes. And can we *pleeeease* put an end to this 1+2+3+4.. =-1/12 bullshit once and for all please. -1/12 is the reiman zeta sum. The reiman zeta function is *NOT* a sum. You might as well assume that because rational numbers have numerators and denominators than $\pi$ does too.

Comment: Your only mistake was posting this question.

Comment: @D_S Oh... snap... that was a little too mean.  It's a legitimate recreational math diversion and humor and fairly harmless and even "healthy" in giving novices things to think about.  But the upshot is.  Divergent series diverge and can not be treated as legitimate sums.  I have to admit $0 = (1 + 2^2 + 3^2 +...) - (1 + 2^2 + 3^2) = 1 + (2^2 - 1) + (3^2 - 2^2) = 1 + 3 + 5+.... $ is really cute and I had never considered it before.

Answer (score 2):

Divergent series diverge and can not be treated as sums.

Therefore

$1 + 2 + 3 + ..... = -1/12$ is not true and makes no sense.  [Yes, I know $\zeta(-1) = -1/12$ but $\zeta(-1) \ne 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5+ ...$.  Yes I know that **IF** $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... $ converged it *would* equal $\zeta(-1)$ but but it *DOESN'T* converge and so it *DOESN'T* equal $\zeta(-1)$.]

Furthermore,  $a = 1 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ....$ is meaningless and $a$ is undefined.  So $a - a$ is meaningless as $a$ is undefined and and does not equal 0.

$(1 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2+..) - (1 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2+..)$ is meaningless and also does not equal 0.

It also doesn't equal $1 + (4-1) + (9-4) + ..$ which in turn does not equal $1 +3 + 5 + $ which is also meaningless.

$(1 + 2 + 3 .....) - (1 + 3 + 5 +7 + ....) = 2 + 4 + 6 + ...$ is meaningless.

$2 + 4 + 6 + .... = 2(1+2+3 +....)$ is meaningless.

$2(1+2+3 + ....) = 1 + 2 + 3+....$ is meaningless.

And $\frac{1+2+3+....}{1+2+3+.....}$ is meaningless and doesn't equal 1.

Everything on this paper, albeit it clever, funny, amusing, and thought provoking, is-- ultimately-- meaningless.